# Oracle Openscript - Not able to record actions performed on applet/form

Tags: applet, oracleforms, openscript

I am testing E-BS with OATS. I am able to record all the web objects and the oracle form is also opened. But OpenScript is unable to identify Applet and any Oracle Forms object. Also, i have noticed while recording my Config Recorder show Applet Recorder status as ‘Starting’ and it never changes to ‘Running’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue Resolved.

Solution-

- Open Java control panel - Security tab, add file:/C:/ in Exception Site list.
- Then record again

Comment: Your answer helped me. I recently started looking into Openscript.  @Bushra Alam, "OpenScript" - Is it a free for an unlimited period or we need to purchase a license?

Answer (score 0):

Run openscript as administrator.

It's solves the issue.